# Excel If Statement Logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that contains all baseball games played for numerous years. I am attempting to create win/loss streaks. I want the formula to check that the team, and the year remain constant while a decision is made based on if the team won or not. I have the data sorted by Team, and the dates are chronological. Previously I had used a nested if statement when I just had the data for one year. The formula that I am attempting to use is

```
=IF(M6=M5, IF(C6=C5, IF(G6="W",1+R5,0)), IF(G6="W",1,0), IF(G6="W",1,0) 

=IF(Team=AboveTeam, If(Year=Aboveyear, If(Result=win, 1+abovewinsteak)), IF(Result=win, 1, 0), IF(result=win,1,0)
```

But I am getting the error that I have too many arguments. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answers below should help. But one tip more or less related tip: Nesting a formula should only be considered, if there is definetly no other way aroung (my opinion). Use Helper-Columns for interim results. That way, you can easily figure out issues with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The top level ‘IF’ statement has too many arguments. The last two IFs seem out of place to me. I’m not sure of your logic, but assuming that you have a bunch of conditions that need to be met, the excel ‘IF’ formula signature is of the form:

```
IF(condition, if_true, if_false)
```

So you always need to put the next ‘IF’ in place of either ‘if_true’ or ‘if_false’. Within each parentheses pair there should be just 3 arguments.

Also, the 2nd IF has too few arguments (no ‘if_false’).

So, assuming that the last two IFs are in error; I *think* your formula should be:

```
=IF(M6=M5, IF(C6=“W”, IF(C6=C5, 1+R5, 1), 0), 0)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last zero in the last formula be `--and(G6="W", C6=C5)`? New year and a win should be 1 not zero.

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement with the condition C6=C5 is the one that had one two few arguments. You can try it this way.

```
=IF(M6=M5, IF(C6=C5, IF(G6="W",1+R5,0), IF(G6="W",1,0)), IF(G6="W",1,0))
```

Here's a rewritten version with fewer if statements and no duplication

```
=IF(G6="W",1+( IF(AND(M6=M5,C6=C5),R5,0)), 0)
```

IF( Result=Win, 1 + ( IF ( Team=AboveTeam AND Year=AboveYear, AboveWinStreak, Year or Team don't match so start over at 0 ), 0 because Result=Loss )

Comment: I think the error the OP is getting is with the extra superfluous IFs in the top level IF. But yes, this is also an error that would be flagged next by excel.

Comment: Nope, I tested it by setting up a spreadsheet with data in those columns and the two additional `IF(G6="W",1,0)` statements are needed in the case of new year and a win or new team and a win